# What do we call "Sad Demise [of someone]" in a newspaper? An Advertisement?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, obituaries

Most of the dictionaries define the word 'advertisement' as an arrangement of picture/video/audio or whatever [to promote](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/advertisement) product/service/person. You see the word 'promotion' there.

Now, the newspapers don't just have advertisements, they have other things too. Here in India, it's quite common to see a spacial space for 'Sad Demise' and other announcements related to final rites and the like. If I want a newspaper to publish this, what should I say?

> Hello, I need to have ______________. It's about the first death anniversary of *someone.*

It should be fitting in here as well...

> Hello, I need to give ________________ about the 'sad demise' of *someone*.

In both the places, using the *advertisement* seems hurting. I'm searching for a word if it defines 'Sad demise', 'First Death Anniversary' etc. So, here, newspapers have ***space for what***? Advertisements? No, they aren't advertisements.

Comment: I need to place an obituary [notice/announcement].  In the news business they're just called "obits"

Comment: If the death was recent, the notice is called an obituary, but it's typically a very dry and factual notice, not an expression of emotion by the deceased's family or friends. A paid notice placed on an anniversary of the death could be called a *memorial* notice, but such notices aren't common in the US, so we don't have a well-established name for them.

Comment: Both are good options. @ThePhoton

Answer (score 4):

You want the [obituaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obituary) department. (e.g.: [LA Times](http://placeanad.latimes.com/obituaries), [Chicago Tribune](http://placeanad.chicagotribune.com/obituaries))

> An obituary is a news article that reports the recent death of a person, typically along with an account of the person's life and information about the upcoming funeral. In large cities and larger newspapers, obituaries are written only for people considered significant. In local newspapers, an obituary may be published for any local resident upon death.

As the article continues, there are also two other options:

> Two types of paid advertisements are related to obituaries. One, known as a death notice, omits most biographical details and may be a legally required public notice under some circumstances. **The other type, a paid memorial advertisement, is usually written by family members or friends, perhaps with assistance from a funeral home.** Both types of paid advertisements are usually run as classified advertisements.

This latter one, in bold, is probably what applies to your question.

If it's on an anniversary, it's called an "in memoriam" notice (in memory) ( e.g.: [LA Times](http://placeanad.latimes.com/in-memoriam), [Chicago Tribune](http://placeanad.chicagotribune.com/in-memoriam)).

The price of publication of these notices varies widely depending on the specific newspaper you're dealing with.

Comment: Strange and shocking, do you still accept this all as an *advertisement?* That's the question. Do you morally accept it? Doesn't it hurt us calling it as an advertisement? +1 though

Comment: It's technically an advertisement but, as I feel I've shown, most people simply call them obituaries or in memoriam notices. They are technically advertisements because you generally pay to place them but they're not regularly **called** ads.

Comment: hhmm that makes sense.